# Appcelerator - Multiple map views in android

Tags: android, dictionary, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to add a map to a second view in the hierarchy of heavyweight windows in my application for android.  This however, is not supported by the android platform, so there has to be some way to add and remove the map to the view as you move back and forth between the windows.

I got it to the point where I can remove the first instance of a map view when moving to child windows, but when I try to navigate back, I can't get the map view to be added back into the parent view.

Below is code that I use to attempt to add the map view back to the view I have created when going back to the parent, but the view doesn't appear.

I've tried reusing the already made instance of the map view, as well as creating a new instance of the map view as the parent view comes into focus.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
win.addEventListener('focus', function(e)
    {   
        mapView.add(map);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with the same thing in my app (http://bit.ly/u2qmbV) and ended up creating  a new map on every 'open' event and ensuring each window closed on each 'blur' event.  I never could get it to work using focus / blur.  I was lucky as I never had to open a new 'map' window from a window that had a map on it.  The only 'hack' I had to use was closing a window in a tab on every 'blur' event for that window so every time you tapped on the tab, it opened again (the Facilities tab / window in the app)